# Convert python http code to C#

Tags: c#, python, converters

I have this code here in python

```
response = requests.post(
    "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v2/profile",
    auth = ("username", "password"),
    headers = {"content-type": "text/plain"},
    data = "your text goes here"
)

jsonProfile = json.loads(response.text)
```

I am trying to convert it to C#, below is my code:

```
public void getRequest() {
        string url = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v2/profile";
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values["username"] = username;
            values["password"] = password;
            values["content-type"] = "text/plain";
            values["data"] = getTestWords(@"D:\Userfiles\tchaiyaphan\Documents\API and Intelligence\storyTestWord.txt");

            var response = client.UploadValues(url, values);

            var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
        }
    }
```

I don't know what to do with header section so i left that out. And when i ran the code it gave me an 401 error. I dont know what to do!

Comment: Debug and check the values of `username` and `password`

Comment: http error 401 means "Unauthorized". Make sure that the username and password are incorrect.

Comment: If the C# fails with 401, then python will as well. This has little to do with converting code between languages

Comment: For the headers try [`WebClient.Headers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code is sending username and password as POST data instead of using the proper HTTP authorization header.

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

Comment: WOW thanks. Now The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type. It stops at line: var response = client.UploadValues(url, values);

Answer (score 0):

Although ThiefMaster had manage to get me pass the authentication but it gave me a different error this time (415 Un-supported media type) so i decided to take a different approach and it works.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v2/profile");

        var postData = getTestWords(@"D:\Userfiles\tchaiyaphan\Documents\API and Intelligence\storyTestWord.txt");

        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/plain";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```